# json_decode to array and non-object

Tags: php

I don't know why I'm getting
Notice: Trying to get property 'date' of non-object
Notice: Trying to get property 'status' of non-object

But when I remove

"order": {
"code": "a123",
"amount": "200",
"buyer": {
"first": "John",
"last": "Doe",
},
"method": {
"type": "Paypal"
},
"status": "progress"
},

I can see result to the "data"

```
$jsonobj = '{
        "order": {
            "code": "a123",
            "amount": "200",
            "buyer": {
                "first": "John",
                "last": "Doe",
            },
            "method": {
                "type": "Paypal"
            },
            "status": "progress"
        },
        "date": "2019-04-02",
        "properties": [
            {
                "name": "WIG",
                "value": "14789"
            }
        ]
    }';

    $obj = json_decode($jsonobj);

    echo $obj->date;
    echo $obj->order->status;
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, because of the comma after `"last": "Doe",`

Comment: Thank you :) Can I validate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have pasted an Invalid Json.
I've removed trailing comma.

```
$jsonobj = '{
           "order":{
              "code":"a123",
              "amount":"200",
              "buyer":{
                 "first":"John",
                 "last":"Doe"
              },
              "method":{
                 "type":"Paypal"
              },
              "status":"progress"
           },
           "date":"2019-04-02",
           "properties":[
              {
                 "name":"WIG",
                 "value":"14789"
              }
           ]
        }';

$obj = json_decode($jsonobj);

echo $obj->date;
echo $obj->order->status;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON String is Invalid. Check this line:

```
"last": "Doe",
```

you have to remove comma end of this line.